# Fallo hibernate org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, struts2

Se ha cambiado la versión de Java de la 1.7 a la 1.8 de un proyecto con Struts 2.5.22 y al subir al servidor el war compilado aparece el siguiente error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken [from com.prueba.struts.pru.ia_routing.ui.dtoimpl.profilenameSendImpl profilenameSendwhere profilenameSend.active=:activeValue order by profilenameSend.profileName]

org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.panic(HqlLexer.java:57)
antlr.CharScanner.setTokenObjectClass(CharScanner.java:340)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.setTokenObjectClass(HqlLexer.java:31)
antlr.CharScanner.<init>(CharScanner.java:51)
antlr.CharScanner.<init>(CharScanner.java:60)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.<init>(HqlBaseLexer.java:56)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.<init>(HqlBaseLexer.java:53)
org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.<init>(HqlBaseLexer.java:50)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.<init>(HqlLexer.java:26)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlParser.getInstance(HqlParser.java:44)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:232)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:155)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:109)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:75)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:54)
org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:71)
org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:13
```

Desde el DAO se ejecuta la query de la siguiente forma:

```
    Session session = getHibernateSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from profilenameSendImpl profilenameSend where profilenameSend.active=:activeValue order by profilenameSend.profileName");

    query.setString("activeValue", Constants.ACTIVEVALUE);
    query.setFirstResult(firstResult - 1); // zero indexed
    query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    List<GMMProfileSend> results = query.list();
```

Con la anterior versión funciona perfectamente

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Hibernate usas?

Comment: @PabloLozano hibernate3. Le adjunto la libreria Hibernate3.jar

Comment: Si estás usando como servidor WebLogic, es posible que el problema sea que ese servidor tiene su propia versión de la libreria ANTLR y no encuentre esa clase